# Geometric rounding with numpy/quantize?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've got a pandas series of data which is a curve.

I want to round it in such a way as to make it 'stepped'. Furthermore, I want the steps to be roughly within 10% of the present value. (Another way of putting this is I want the steps to increase in increments of 10%, i.e. geometrically).

I've written something that's iterative and slow:

```
def chunk_trades(A):
    try:
        last = A[0]
    except:
        print(A)
        raise
    new = []
    for x in A.iteritems():
        if not last or np.abs((x[1]-last)/last) > 0.1:
            new.append(x[1])
            last = x[1]
        else:
            new.append(last)
    s = pd.Series(new, index=A.index)
    return s
```

I don't want to use this code.

I'm trying to find a faster, pythonic way of doing this. I've tried using numpy.digitize() but I don't think that's what I'm looking for. Any ideas for how best to approach this?

Comment: Why do you not want `numpy.digitize`?

Comment: Well the range is potentially 0 to infinity, and I'm not sure how to make it geometric.

Comment: OK I've just come up with this: np.exp(round(10*np.log(abs(j)))/10) which is sort of the right direction...

Comment: Well, you could also say `np.exp(np.round(np.log(abs(j), 1)))` with the same effect. Just saves another division. BTW did you mean to use 10** and np.log10 instead?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. This is good though, looks like the right direction. I tried with 10** but the jumps are a bit too large; I'm just trying to think about how to control the step size...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think the solution should be something like:

```
np.exp(np.around(np.log(np.abs(j)), decimals=1)) * np.sign(j)
```

Map to logarithmic space, do the rounding, transform back.